# Assigning variable a math code

Tags: macros

I want all `s2` words inside of my large text be automatically recognized as $\rm s^2$, so that when I have numbers of constants such as `9.8 m/s2`, they will be automatically recognized as `9.8 m/{$\rm s^2$}` and be compiled as such.

Comment: How about a different approach using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) where you assign a macro and use it `\acc{9.8}` to yield `9.8 m/s²`?

Comment: I am aware of the siunitx package. The problem is I need to copy/paste large amount of text from a testbank word document into TeX. To use siunitx would be even more difficult.

Comment: Is there anything that would prevent you and globally replacing all instances of `s2` with `s\textsuperscript{2}`?

Comment: You can search and replace in the Word document.

Comment: if your `s2` already were in math mode, that would be easier, but here it seems from the context that they are not. `LaTeX` is supposed to be a mark-up language and your source has no mark-up if all `s2`'s and `9.8 m/s2` are encountered naked in pure text. If you had asked for `/s2` that would be easier, because it is feasible to "activate" `/` whereas "activating" the letter `s` is simply not an option (except if you had already your source with all the `s2`'s already in math mode).

Comment: You may *want* something, but it's unpolite asking so nonetheless. What you'd like to obtain is essentially impossible, because it would break all macros containing `s` in their name. Fixing bad input is better done with a “search and replace” method.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you want, but close, I hope.

1. Using an editor replace all `s2` (observe the space) by, say, `\seckw2`.
2. `\def\seckw#1{$\mathrm{s^{#1}}$}`.

There are other methods, but some aditional knowledge about your entries is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid replacing all text from the original is not an option. I may need to re-copy and paste them somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're free to use LuaLaTeX, you could use it as a preprocessor to replace all instances of `s2` with `\ensuremath{\textnormal{s}^2}` "on the fly". The code given below works by assigning the function that performs this replacement to the `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates *before* TeX begins its usual processing.

That said, I think you're better off in the medium to long run familiarizing yourself with the `siunitx` package and getting used to writing, say, `\SI{9.81}{\meter\per\second\squared}`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\ensuremath" macro
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function s2 ( x )
  x = string.gsub ( x , "s2" , "\\ensuremath{\\textnormal{s}^2}" )
  return x
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , s2 , "s2" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
9.81\,m/s2, $9.81\,\textrm{m}/s2$
\end{document}
```